# Spring Boot Hibernate Child Table PK incorrectly is being linked to Parent Table PK

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In Parent Table

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "item")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = 
"item")
List<ItemTxn> itemTxns;
```

In Child Table

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "itemTxn")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Item item;
```

Let's say my Parent table as a row with a pkid 1;
In Child Table 
I have a row with 
pkid -2
parent_table-id - 1;

The data will correctly be inserted
parent_table-id correctly refers to the parent table
But the pkid  column in the child table also created a FK link to the parent table id column.

How can i prevent this?

Edit:

[The Item_ID column in item_txn table correctly has a fk to the parent table - item on the ID column
But the id column on the item_txn table is incorrectly referencing back to the item table id column as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwK6c.png)

Comment: But the pkid column in the child table also created a FK link to the parent table id column. // Can you post a screenshot of the data that you are seeing in the DB and what you are expecting to see?

Comment: @Ranjith added in the screenshot